# XML scheme to scheme conversion with Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I am a writer of books and I am new to Python. The question I have is strategic. I write my manuscripts into an xml-file with proprietary tags (they have a size around 1 MB and 5000-1000 lines):

```
manuscript.xml
<h>Title of Chapter</h>
<p>This is a sentence, with one word written in <i>italics</i></p>
```

I often want to output what I have written so far and I am trying to create a fully automated workflow with Python. Python should convert my XML into two different XML-schemes:

```
1. HTML for epub (with creating IDs):
<h1 id="title-of-chapter">Title of Chapter</h1>
<p>This is a sentence, with one word written in <i>italics</i></p>
```

Then save as manuscript.html.

```
2. ODT:
<text:h text:style-name="HeadlineStyle1" text:outline-level="1">GetByName</text:h>
<text:p text:style-name="ParagraphStyle1">This is a sentence, with one word written in <text:span text:style-name="Italics">italics</text:span></text:p>
```

Then save as content.xml

I am not sure whether I should really parse the XML (original XML → dict → new XML) at all. Wouldn't it be easier to handle the original file as plain text and to let Python just convert the tags, thus <p> becomes <text:p text:style-name="ParagraphStyle1">?

On the other side, the task above is only the first step. Later on, I would like to make Python create a table of contents by collecting all headlines and write it into the helper file toc.ncx and finally letting Python zip all those files into an epub-container.

There are alot of tutorials out there about xml → dict, but it is hard to find something about the second step dict → xml which goes into details.

Comment: XML to XML transformations are best done with XSLT, not Python.

Comment: I forgot to mention: XSLT can't do this.

Comment: When you write your manuscripts how do you mark them up? How do you mark up a phrase that is to be put in italics. Or, put another way, what software do you use to record your manuscripts?

Comment: @user2240646: *I forgot to mention: XSLT can't do this.*  That unsubstantiated statement is almost certainly wrong, even taking into account that you've not defined (and probably do not understand yourself) what *this* is.

Comment: Bill: Exactly as given above, I put them in <i>-tags. The first draft is written in Word, then I transfer it to Notepad++ and clean it up with proper markup.

kjhughes: I do alot of XSLT on my website, but here we are dealing with text document xml where you cannot predict which tag comes next. But the order of the elements has to be maintained. Moreover, I still would have to use XSLT inside Python. For starters, how would you tell XSLT how all these tags should be converted?

Answer (score 0):

It is easily possible to rename tags in ElementTree:

```
for oldTag in root.iter('oldtag'):
   oldTag.tag = 'newtag'
```

XSLT cannot do that. It cannot transform XML, it can only pick elements out of it.

Comment: If it's definitely so, it must be easy for you to give an example for XSLT iterating through unforseeable tags of a plain text xml file and replacing them by keeping the order of the elements. Just name the command.